# How many 'CUDA cores' does each multiprocessor of a GPU have?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I know that devices before the Fermi architecture had 8 SPs in a single multiprocessor. Is the count same in Fermi architecture?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The number of **Multiprocessors (MP)** and the number of **cores** per MP can be found by executing **DeviceQuery.exe**. It is found in the `%NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT%/C/bin` directory of the GPU Computing SDK installation.

A look at the code of DeviceQuery (found in `%NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT%/C/src/DeviceQuery`) reveals that it the number of cores is calculated by passing the x.y **CUDA Capability** numbers to the **ConvertSMVer2Cores** utility function.

From the code of **ConvertSMVer2Cores** this relationship between the capability and core count can be seen:

| Capability | Cores |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 8 |
| 11 | 8 |
| 12 | 8 |
| 13 | 8 |
| 20 | 32 |
| 21 | 48 |

Answer (score 15):

The answer depends on the Compute Capability property of the CUDA device. The numbers are:

1. Compute Capability <= 1.3 --> 8 CUDA Cores / SM
2. CC == 2.0 --> 32 CUDA cores / SM
3. CC == 2.1 --> 48 CUDA cores / SM

See appendix G of the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

Update of @AshwinNanjappa's answer for CUDA 7.5:

| Compute Capability | # Cores |
| --- | --- |
| 1.x: | 8 |
| 2.0: | 32 |
| 2.1: | 48 |
| 3.x: | 192 |
| 5.x: | 128 |

Notes:

- CUDA 7.5 no longer supports device with compute capability 1.x.
- These aren't really 'cores' in the sense of CPU cores. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976556/what-is-the-difference-between-cuda-core-and-cpu-core) here on Stack Overflow.
- In Maxwell GPUs (5.x), the number of 'cores' per multiprocessor has *decreased*.
- I got the additional information from `$CUDA_SAMPLES_DIR/common/inc/helper_cuda.h`.