# How to get details about NVIDIA GPU?

Tags: cuda

I want to know the detailed specification about my NVIDIA Quadro K2000 GPU. I want to know the number of SM, number of SP per SM. I have read several questions about it at SO but most of them are old, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217167/cuda-how-many-cores-per-mp), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/198119/streaming-multiprocessor-number) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639766/does-multiprocessorcount-gives-the-number-of-streaming-multiprocessors).

Some people have said to run `deviceQuery.exe` and it will give the details about your GPU but I do not have any `deviceQuery.exe` available in my system (I have searched, checked the location suggested).

PS: I am using Windows-7, 64 bit.

Comment: From FAQ of the https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads                  Q: What is the difference between the Network Installer and the Local Installer?
A: The Local Installer has all of the components embedded into it (toolkit, driver, samples).      So you just need to install the Local installer and allow the samples to be installed

Comment: @Iman: Actually the Sample files were already there but the folder ProgramData was by default hidden and that is why, I was not able to search it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the nVidia SDK from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) and compile `deviceQuery.exe` by yourself. See the [getting starded](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7_0/Prod/doc/CUDA_Getting_Started_Windows.pdf) guide page 7

Comment: The page-7 says that the `deviceQuery.exe` is located at `C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v7.0\bin\win64\Release
` but in my system, that path does not contain that `.exe` file.

Comment: You need to compile it by yourself. See page 9.

Comment: @damienfrancois I see that this is old, but I do not see any instructions to compile on Page 9, just saying that the files should be there.

Answer (score 0):

The CUDA Samples are not shipped as pre-built binaries. So, we need to compile it ourself.

I have used Visual Studio-2012 to build `Samples.sln` present in `C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v7.0`.

**UPDATE:** I would also like to add here that by default, the CUDA installer puts the Sample files in `C:\ProgramData......` but some time the folder `ProgramData` is hidden and that's why I was not able to search the sample files at my system. So, you need to unhide `ProgramData` folder to find the `Sample files` of CUDA.

Comment: @talonmies: Changed the sentence. Btw, the previous sentence was written at  `dev talks` of CUDA forum.

Comment: Every version of CUDA I was using came with binaries for all samples (versions 5.5 - 7.5RC on Windows platform).